# Al ir a una página se me va abajo

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo esta linea de código HTML:

```
<a href="{{ url('/articulo_comentarios/'.$articulo->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Más información</a>
```

Esta me lleva a una página dentro de mi proyecto de Laravel, pero noto un problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando voy a la página, empieza en una parte muy baja. Extrañamente otras páginas empiezan en la parte superior.
¿Cómo obligo a que al ir a esa empiece en la parte más arriba?

Más datos: Esta es la vista que quiero ver:

```
<?php
    use App\Articulo;

    if($articulo->estado==2 && $visto){
        if(substr($articulo->texto,Articulo::limite-1,1)==" ")
            $texto=substr($articulo->texto,0,Articulo::limite-1);
        else
            $texto=substr($articulo->texto,0,Articulo::limite);
        $texto.="...";
        }
    else
        $texto=$articulo->texto;

    if($visto)
        $clase="col-md-4";
    else
        $clase="col-md-6";
    $categoria=$articulo->categoria();
?>

<div class="{{$clase}} card card-1">
    <h2 class="text-center card-title">{{$articulo->titulo}}</h2>
    <hr>
    <center>
        @if($categoria=="columna")
            <h4><img class="card-img-top" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius:150px;" src="{{url($articulo->user->ruta())}}"/> {{$articulo->user->nombre()}}</h4>
            <br>
        @else
            <span class="badge badge-cat badge-info" style="white-space: pre-line;">Esta noticia de {{$articulo->tipo->nombre}} la escribio {{$articulo->user->nombre()}}</span><br>
        @endif
        <span class="badge badge-cat badge-info" style="white-space: pre-line;">Esta {{$categoria}} ha sido publicada el {{$articulo->creado()}}</span>
        @if($articulo->created_at<$articulo->updated_at)
            <br><span class="badge badge-cat badge-info" style="white-space: pre-line;">Fue actualizada por última vez el {{$articulo->cambiado()}}</span>
        @endif
    </center>
    <hr>
    <img class="card-img-top" style="width: auto; height: 300px;" src="{{url($articulo->foto->ruta())}}"/>
    <hr>
    <h3 class="text-left" style="white-space: pre-line;">{{$texto}}</h3>
    <hr>
    <div class="card-body">
    @if($articulo->estado==2 && $visto)
        <a href="{{ url('/articulo_comentarios/'.$articulo->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Más información</a>
    @endif

    @if($articulo->estado!=2 && auth()->user()->ocupacion_id==1)
        <a href="{{ url('/articulo_seleccion/'.$articulo->id) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Publicar la {{$categoria}}</a>
        <a href="{{ url('/articulo_rechazar/'.$articulo->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Rechazar la {{$categoria}}</a>
        <a href="{{ url('/articulo_eliminar/'.$articulo->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Borrar la {{$categoria}}</a>
    @endif
    @if($visto && auth()->check() && auth()->user()->activado && auth()->user()->navegacion()=="redactar" && auth()->user()->id==$articulo->user_id)
        <?php
            $fotos=App\Foto::latest()->get();
            $pig=0;
            while($fotos[$pig]->id!=$articulo->foto_id)
                $pig++;
            $pig=floor($pig/Articulo::margen)+1;
        ?>

        <a href="{{ url('/articulo_modificar/'.$articulo->id.'?page='.$pig) }}" class="btn btn-course btn-block">Modificar la {{$categoria}}</a>
    @endif
    @if($articulo->estado==2 && !$visto)
        <a href="{{ url('/articulo_imprimir/'.$articulo->id) }}" class="btn btn-course btn-block">Descargar como un Fichero PDF</a>
        @include('redes')
        <hr>
        @include('comentado')
        <hr>
        @include('formulon')
    @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

He descubierto que el problema radica en `formulon`, que es un formulario:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-25">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Publicar un comentario</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{route('comentario.publicar',$articulo)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf

                        <input type="hidden" name="articulo_id" value="{{ $articulo->id }}"/>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Correo</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="ej: lola@mail.com" required>

                                @if($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="nombre" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Nombre</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="nombre" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('nombre') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="nombre" value="{{ old('nombre') }}" placeholder="ej: Paco Flores" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('nombre'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('nombre') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="texto" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Comentario</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <textarea id="texto" name="texto" placeholder="Escribe aquí tu comentario">{{old('texto')}}</textarea>

                                @if ($errors->has('texto'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('texto') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Publicar comentario
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y más concretamente, el problema radica justo en este fragmento:

```
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="nombre" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Nombre</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="nombre" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('nombre') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="nombre" value="{{ old('nombre') }}" placeholder="ej: Paco Flores" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('nombre'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('nombre') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo descubri.
El problema estaba en el `autofocus` que habia en la caja del formulario para la variable `nombre`. Al quitarlo ya no desciende la página.